# Not able to get the value from parameter in apigateway integration request mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

in the integration request of my api gtw I have the following mapping:

```
{  "searchQuery": "$input.params('searchQuery')"}
```

and all is good.
However I need to do it this way to avoid the double qoute issues:

```
#set ($param = $util.escapeJavaScript($input.params()))
 {  "searchQuery": "$param('searchQuery')"}
```

but when I check the passing result in lambda this is what I see:

```
searchQuery
```

And I expect to see the value related to searchQuery passed as a parameter.
Any idea?
How can do this in the proper way?

```
$param('searchQuery')
```

Answer (score 0):

You've a typo in the params function. It should be:

`$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params())`

Comment: I fixed it but same issue